# If C = (F^-1) AF and also C = (G^-1)BG, what matrix M gives B = (M^-1)AM?

Tags: matrices

Second part of the question: If C is similar to A and also to B then __ 
(Not sure if this is correct but I answer: A is similar to B?)

Please help me with the first part of the question, I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $C = F^{-1}AF$ and $C = G^{-1}BG$ then we can $FC = FF^{-1}AF \implies FC = AF \implies FCF^{-1}=A$ but we also know that $C = G^{-1}BG$ so we get 
$$FG^{-1}BGF^{-1}=A$$ 
but because I am dumb :) and solved this the wrong way we have to re-arrange it to get 
$$B=GF^{-1}AG^{-1}F$$  so $M=G^{-1}F$